# Azure Data Factory mapping part of a value

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm copying data from an CSV file in Azure Blob storage to Azure Table storage with Azure Data Factory v2.
One of the columns in the sources contains UK post codes, e.g. RM1 1AA. I'd like to use the first part as a Partition Key in the table.

I'm trying to use dynamic content, but I can't find a function to target the value. My column is called "pcds". What do I write instead of the "???" to make it capture the first part from the pcds column?

[image]

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions), you can not set dynamic content for the source column.You could set partition key as source column exactly or just set it from parameters.

[image]

However, I provide you with a workaround. You could use [Azure Funtion Table Storage Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table) to process the partition key as your want when it is inserted into Table Storage.Just get the partition key value and use `str.Substring` method in Azure Function code.

Hope it helps you.